# how to store values from command prompt in an empty python dictionary?

Tags: python, linux, dictionary

Here is the code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p1 = Popen(["sysctl", "-a"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", "net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
output = p2.communicate()[0]
print output

p1 = Popen(["sysctl", "-a"], stdout=PIPE)
p3 = Popen(["grep", "net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
output1 = p3.communicate()[0]
print output1

p1 = Popen(["sysctl", "-a"], stdout=PIPE)
p4 = Popen(["grep", "net.ipv4.ip_forward"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
output2 = p4.communicate()[0]
print output2

p1 = Popen(["sysctl", "-a"], stdout=PIPE)
p5 = Popen(["grep", "net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
output3 = p5.communicate()[0]
print output3

p1 = Popen(["sysctl", "-a"], stdout=PIPE)
p6 = Popen(["grep", "net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
output4 = p6.communicate()[0]
print output4

p1 = Popen(["sysctl", "-a"], stdout=PIPE)
p7 = Popen(["grep", "net.ipv4.conf.all.log.martians"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
output5 = p7.communicate()[0]
print output5

p1 = Popen(["sysctl", "-a"], stdout=PIPE)
p8 = Popen(["grep", "net.ipv4.conf.all.secure_redirects"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
output6 = p8.communicate()[0]
print output6

p1 = Popen(["sysctl", "-a"], stdout=PIPE)
p9 = Popen(["grep", "net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
output7 = p9.communicate()[0]
print output7

p1 = Popen(["sysctl", "-a"], stdout=PIPE)
p10 = Popen(["grep", "net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route"], stdin=p1.stdout,  stdout=PIPE)
output8 = p10.communicate()[0]
print output8

p1 = Popen(["sysctl", "-a"], stdout=PIPE)
p11 = Popen(["grep", "net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
output9 = p11.communicate()[0]
print output9


p1 = Popen(["sysctl", "-a"], stdout=PIPE)
p12 = Popen(["grep", "net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
output10 = p12.communicate()[0]
print output10

current_kernel_para = dict()            #new dictionary to store the above kernel parameters
```

The output of above program is:

```
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 0

net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts = 1

net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0

net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1

net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 0

net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 0

net.ipv4.conf.all.secure_redirects = 1

net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 1

net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route = 0

net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 1

net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 512
```

I want to store these values in a dictionary "current_kernel_para". The desired output is:
{net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all:0, net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts:1} etc.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could just split the string at the "=" and use the first as key and second token as value.

Answer (score 0):

split the output on the '='

```
x = output.split(' = ')
```

This would give:

```
['net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects', '1']
```

You can then add all these lists together and use:

```
x = ['net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all', '0', 'net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects', '1'...]
dict_x = dict(x[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(x), 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
current_kernel_para = {}
paras = ["net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all",
        "net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts", #...
       ]
for para in paras:
    p1 = Popen(["sysctl", "-a"], stdout=PIPE)
    p2 = Popen(["grep", para], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
    output = p2.communicate()[0]
    output.strip()
    k, v = map(strip, output.split('='))
    current_kernel_para[k] = v
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than assigning each output to a new variable, just collect it as a list. Remember to strip the trailing `\n`

```
outputs = []

p1 = Popen(["sysctl", "-a"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", "net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
outputs.append(p2.communicate()[0].strip('\n'))

p1 = Popen(["sysctl", "-a"], stdout=PIPE)
p3 = Popen(["grep", "net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
outputs.append(p3.communicate()[0].strip('\n'))
```

This gives

```
>>> outputs
['net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 0', 'net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts = 1']
```

Then you can split each string in the list at `=` and collect the result as a `list of lists`.

```
outputs_list=[x.split('=') for x in outputs]
```

Gives

```
>>> outputs_list
[['net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all ', ' 0'], ['net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts ', ' 1']]
```

Good, but it has leading/trailing spaces. Lets strip those out too

```
outputs_list=[[y.strip() for y in x.split('=')] for x in outputs]
```

This gives

```
>>> outputs_list
[['net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all', '0'], ['net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts', '1']]
```

Pass it too the `dict()` constructor to form a dictionary

```
>>> dict(outputs_list)
{'net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all': '0', 'net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts': '1'}
```